# Where can I find test-ether for the Kovan Test Network?

Tags: ether, testnets, contract-debugging, kovan, faucets

I have tried getting some using my github account but my account got flagged immediately and the program wasn't recognizing my account (Since it wasn't public due to being flagged). Are there any alternatives? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are looking for is a _faucet_. https://github.com/kovan-testnet/faucet or ask in https://gitter.im/kovan-testnet/faucet

Comment: Can you please add a snippet from the github page as a response to mark you as correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here's](https://github.com/kovan-testnet/faucet/blob/master/README.md) a link to information on *faucets* for the Kovan testnet.

There are currently four ways listed on the above link to get Kovan testnet ETH:

> - Icarus Faucet (SMS Verified, Automated)
> - Request Via Gitter (Manually Verified)
> - Use PoW via SmartPool

Answer (score 4):

Use the gitter app, this is the best way to get ether in Kovan Testnet,
URL: https://gitter.im/kovan-testnet/faucet

Upon going to the above url, post your kovan address to instantly get 5 ether to your mentioned address.

Comment: I got 3 and now have to wait 6 days...

Comment: when you say instantly.. do you mean not immediately? I seem to be having a wait time, maybe I put the wrong address in..?

Comment: It is specific to address. For the same address, it will take a long time. So either create multiple addresses or dont use up all the available eth.

Answer (score 1):

As of **Aug 2021**, there are two working methods I know of (that work instantly):

1. Post your address here (once in 24h): https://gitter.im/kovan-testnet/faucet
2. Connect your metamask and request 0.01 KETH here: https://app.mycrypto.com/faucet

Answer (score 0):

Currently the most reliable method is through https://faucets.chain.link/ which provides .1 KETH per 24 hours.

The manual gitter sent me .001, which is more of an insult than anything.

Did not try Icarus method because you have to spend mainnet ETH to use their SMS.

app.mycrypto.com wasn't working at all at the time of this writing.

You can also get it at ethdrop.dev but it's only .001 as well, but it works 4 times in 24 hours so..there is that.

Answer (score 0):

Found these two useful websites for adding eths

https://faucets.chain.link/

https://ethdrop.dev/

Answer (score 0):

As a result of the recent Ethereum merge, the testnets Kovan, Ropsten, and Rinkeby have been deprecated. At the time, the only Ethereum testnet is Goerli.

Here's a reliable Goerli faucet - https://goerlifaucet.com/.

If you're like me and need some good web3 dev resources - https://docs.alchemy.com.