# Is kovan network died?

Tags: ether, kovan

Kovan's network faucet is inactive. I have only found a few "faucets" that give me 0.01 or 0.1 test Ether every 24 hours...

https://faucet.kovan.network

This is the [Kovan Token contract](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x4d6bb4ed029b33cf25d0810b029bd8b1a6bcab7b). Its Off since 21 days ago

What is happening?
Someone could fund me some Ethers for still working..? (please and thanks)

0xdF6e07E4D432638CE80B73cFaF127678eF4D7E6E

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find test-ether for the Kovan Test Network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24789/where-can-i-find-test-ether-for-the-kovan-test-network)

Comment: No. Excuse me but its an old post with outdated solutions

Comment: I was able to get some (usually 1 or 6 every 24h) using the Gitter one : https://gitter.im/kovan-testnet/faucet. It may be the only one still active though. Also, I'm not a fan of the mandatory login.

Comment: https://faucet.kovan.network  is ACTIVE again now. (2 Ethers each 24h)